# Time machine backup is very slow (new TM drive and large amount of data)

Tags: time-machine, backup, performance, macos

I have data (mostly photos) on an external WD 2Tb drive (about 930gb)
I have just installed a 3Tb Lacie drive and want to use it as the TM drive to back up the external WD drive and the Mac HD (very little data on this)
While I expected the first back-up to take some time it seems to be running at about 1.2mb sec which seems very slow especially using USB3 etc
At this rate the system estimated 8 days to build the new TM drive
Is this reasonable or is there something I can do to improve the process speed
All comments welcome

Answer (score 2):

I recently added a 4TB external drive to back up my Mac Pro.  I had about 2.4 TB of data in the initial pass of the backup with TM.  It took about 9 hours to complete.  I'm not sure the initial estimate is accurate, but it does take a very long time on the initial pass.  Once that is done though, the incremental updates are very quick.

I think in this case you just have to be patient, and don't pay too much attention to the estimate of completion time.